# Unity, bool variable in my script doesn't changes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have the class `PlayerController`

```cs
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool isMoveable;

    public void Init()
    {
        isMoveable = false;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        ...
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isMoveable)
        {
            MovePlayer();
        }
    }

    public void EnableMovement()
    {
        isMoveable = true;
    }

    void MovePlayer()
    {
    }
}
```

I have class `GameMaster`

```cs
public the class GameMaster : MonoBehaviour
{
    PlayerController playerController;

    private void Start()
    {
        playerController.Init();
    }

    public void StartGame()
    {
        playerController.EnableMovement();
        uiManager.OnGameStarted();
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to start the game by clicking a button that activates `StartGame()`. But `MovePlayer()` never got called, but if I print `Debug.Log(isMoveable)` in EnableMovement, I get `True`.

I have tried to change `isMoveable` by int and enum but that didn't help.

Comment: @LiorV please familiarise yourself with how unity works before trying to answer questions on it. `FixedUpate` is a Unity Event function, it is called via a specific engine mechanism

Comment: Maybe the Player object is not Active? In GameMaster.Start() add playerController.gameObject.SetActive(true); before the Init() call might help.

Comment: I would start with trying to log something inside of `PlayerController`'s `FixedUpdate`. If nothing prints in the console, then `PlayerController` might not be active like @Dustin_00 mentioned.